# How can I answer this," How is life on work front?"

Tags: word-usage, sentence

I mean work front is just confusing me .

Comment: It means, "How is your job going?"  Not necessarily the technical part, but working environment, length of work day, friendly people, etc.

Comment: As per the example in the answer by @WS2 it should be ***the** work front*.

Answer (score 5):

It is a frequently-used metaphor, which breaks down one's life into a series of military "fronts" e.g. *home front, work front, leisure front*, etc. It is often used where a person is known to be going through difficult times - so they may be looking at life in terms of a military campaign.

So "How's life on the work front?" simply means "How is life for you at work right now?"

Comment: 'Front' is more user-friendly than 'sphere' and certainly 'domain'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Essentially because it carries heavy irony. Whoever thought of one's work life as being like the Somme in 1915?

Comment: I don't think so; I'd say it's a dead metaphor nowadays. The 'home front' sounds almost cosy to people who've not experienced the War (ie most of us).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth You don't have to have experienced war to know that "front" equals human carnage. Who decides when a metaphor is "dead"?

Comment: I asked the same question here years ago. // I've just asked an educated  67-year-old 'What's happening on the quarterly meeting front?', received a sensible answer, then asked her 'Did the word 'front' give rise to any subtexts relating to war?' Guess what answer I got.

Answer (score 0):

Well work front can Also be used/called things such as the following. Job, used in phrases such as *Time to get back to reality of 'making that money!!" Or can be used like this, "I am so not looking forward to getting back to Adulting tomorrow!!" Adulting (v): to do grown up things and hold responsibilities such as, a 9-5 job, a mortgage/rent, a car payment, or anything else that makes one think of grown ups. Or here is other words in relation to working. Career structure, function, labor, livelihood, occupation, position, service, slot, walk of life, working life, work load. Hope I was somewhat of a assistance to your question.